# couldn't start TLS [Perl]

Tags: windows, perl, ssl

i'm trying to send an email with perl. my code run on linux with no error.
but when i run my code on windows server 2008 r2 , perl sys :

> Couldn't start TLS: SSL version SSLv3 not Supported.

my perl code :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Net::SMTP::TLS;
use 5.010;

my $mailer = new Net::SMTP::TLS(
        'smtp.mail.yahoo.com',
        Hello   =>      'smtp.mail.yahoo.com',
        Port    =>      587,
        User    =>      'someEmail@yahoo.com',
        Password=>      'password');
    $mailer->mail('someEmail@yahoo.com');
    $mailer->to('someEmail@yahoo.com');
    $mailer->data();
    $mailer->datasend("From: someEmail@yahoo.com\n");
    $mailer->datasend("To: someEmail@yahoo.com\n");
    $mailer->datasend("Subject: test&test\n");
    $mailer->datasend("Content-type: text/html\n\n");
    $mailer->datasend("\n");
    $mailer->datasend"test test ste  tset\n");
    $mailer->dataend();
    $mailer->quit;
```

also i tried :
http://www.techieshelp.com/how-to-enable-ssl-3-0-server-2008-sbs-2008/

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/74a45b74-8d84-4308-ba14-02e4bc724e27/ssl-v3-on-windows-2008?forum=winservergen

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of all keys and sub-keys expanded under `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders \SCHANNEL\Protocols\`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Net::SMTP::TLS is old, very old. The last version is from 2006. And it is buggy. And the bugs cause the problems you have. There is an unofficial replacement Net::SMTP::TLS_ButMaintained but this considers itself deprecated too (last version from 2013).

It will also not help to fiddle around with SSL controls of Windows, since Perl will not use the SSL stack from Windows but instead uses OpenSSL.

I recommend that you use the recent versions of [Net::SMTP](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SMTP) instead. Since version 3.0 it has support for both kinds of TLS, i.e. explicit using STARTTLS (that's what you need) and implicit by directly connecting to the SSL port. It even supports IPv6.

With a current Net::SMTP, a recent IO::Socket::SSL (for the SSL part) and Authen::SASL (for the login part) you can do the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::SMTP 3.03;
my $mailer = Net::SMTP->new(
    'smtp.mail.yahoo.com',
    Hello   =>      'smtp.mail.yahoo.com',
    Port    =>      587,
);

$mailer->starttls();
$mailer->auth('someEmail@yahoo.com','password');
$mailer->mail(...)
```

Comment: hi Steffen,thanks for answer ,after edit my code with your code perl sys me : Can't locate object method "starttls" via package "Net::SMTP"

Comment: @user3001228: then you are not using a recent Net::SMTP. In my code example I have an explicit requirement for 3.03 or newer since the feature is only available since version 3 as I described.

Comment: ok i installed "libnet-3.07" but sys : Net::SMTP version 3.07 required--this is only version 2.34 . what is problem ??!!??

Comment: @user3001228: My guess is that you did not install it properly and that the old version of Net::SMTP is in your include path before the new version.

Comment: ok finally i installed Net::SMTP version 3.07 and my code have no any error but doesn't send any mail !

Comment: @user3001228: use `Debug => 1` to see what's going on.

Comment: excuse me how i can solve this : Net::SMTP: Net::Cmd::getline(): unexpected EOF on command channel: Bad file descriptor at test.pl line 16.

Comment: and this : Net::SMTP: Net::Cmd::_is_closed(): unexpected EOF on command channel: Bad file descriptor at test.pl line 17.

Comment: @user3001228: I have no idea what you are exactly doing and your original code has no error handling. I can only recommend to add error handling, add `Debug => 1` to see what's going on and if you still have problems provide the code and the debug output so that others can also see what's going on.

Comment: Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2a71b88)>>> EHLO smtp.mail.yahoo.com
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2a71b88)<<< 250-smtp.mail.yahoo.com
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2a71b88)<<< 250-PIPELINING
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2a71b88)<<< 250-SIZE 41697280
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2a71b88)<<< 250-8 BITMIME
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2a71b88)<<< 250 STARTTLS
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2a71b88)>>> STARTTLS
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2a71b88)<<< 220 2.0.0 Start TLS
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2a71b88)>>> RCPT TO:<hosein.iprogramer.com>
Net::SMTP: Net::Cmd::getline(): unexpected EOF on command channel: Bad file descriptor at test.pl line 16.

Comment: @user3001228: please do not cut and paste code into the comments. It's simply unreadable. Edit your question instead or ask a new one. I would prefer that you ask a new one since this problem you have asked here is resolved. These are other problems now